# Android AdMob Error The ad size and ad unit ID must be set before load is called

Tags: android, admob

Hi I'm trying to add ads into my application but i keep getting the error

```
The ad size and ad unit ID must be set before load is called.
```

heres what i have tried so far

heres my layout (I have the actual adUnitId number that i have put in the xml in my app just havn't put it in here as i didnt think it would be a good idea to post it online)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/levelView" 
     >

     <RelativeLayout 
      android:id="@+id/header" 
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="70dp"
      >


          <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="hello"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"/>

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/headertitle"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:layout_below="@+id/headertitle"
           android:textSize="40dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="2014"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"/>

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/imageView1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/headertitle"
             android:src="@drawable/level_logo" />

    </RelativeLayout>


   <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:listSelector="@null"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
    </GridView>



  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_below="@+id/gridView1"
                         ads:adUnitId="MY ID NUMBER"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

And then in my onCreate() im running the following function

```
 public void loadAds(){
        // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
        AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest); 
        }
```

Does anyone know what the error means and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 13):

Change the `xmlns:ads` schema

from

```
 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

to

```
 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The com.google.ads namespace is wrong and should be changed as suggested here.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer it was to change

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_below="@+id/gridView1"
                         ads:adUnitId="MY ID NUMBER"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

to

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"

                         xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                         ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"
                         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                         >

  </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: I would recommend against putting your AD unit ID/publisher ID in a public message.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same error and finally used code instantiation to solve the issue.

Comment: Bukeridge can you explain a bit further im not sure what you mean. Ps Thanks for the help i appriciate it

Answer (score 0):

Change your this code

```
   <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_below="@+id/gridView1"
                     ads:adUnitId="MY ID NUMBER"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

to

```
   <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"

                     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                     ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-8510605212168324/8634800090"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"
                     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                     >
```

and Remove

```
                xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```